# Add every scraped item to csv row pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, selenium

I have a selenium project that scrape website and loop to get inner class text

I want to save every scraped text from this loop to a new csv row located next to the py file, and accept new columns if added in the future
How do i do that?

This is what i tried

```
prodTitle = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(@class,'itemTitle')]")
for pTitle in prodTitle:
    itemName = pTitle
    pd = pd.dataframe(pTitle.text)
    pd.to_csv('data.csv', pd)
    print(pTitle.text)
```

but it add the last item only

Comment: Is there anything you tried and did not work ?

Comment: Yes i tried using dataframe in a for loop to add the scrapped text to csv file, but it add the last item only

Comment: This is what i tried
prodTitle = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(@class,'itemTitle')]")
for pTitle in prodTitle:
    itemName = pTitle
    pd = pd.dataframe(pTitle.text)
    pd.to_csv('data.csv', pd)
    print(pTitle.text)

Comment: You should mention inside the question what exactly have you tried so far (present the code) and mention what exactly, specific problems / errors do you have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the data in the same loop and then save the whole dataframe, like this:

```
prodTitle = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(@class,'itemTitle')]")
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Title'])

for (idx,pTitle) in enumerate(prodTitle):
    itemName = pTitle
    df.loc[idx, 'Title'] = pTitle.text
    print(pTitle.text)
    
df.to_csv('data.csv')
```

**EDIT:** to add more data it is convenient set the column before the loop, like this:

```
cols = ['Title', 'Col_0', 'Col_1', 'Col_N']
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=cols)
```

and then inside the loop:

```
...
df.loc[idx, 'Title'] = title
df.loc[idx, 'Col_0'] = data_0
df.loc[idx, 'Col_1'] = data_1
df.loc[idx, 'Col_N'] = data_N
...
```

**EDIT (because I found another way):**

You can create a list with all the data and then passed them to a DataFrame:

```
prodTitle = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(@class,'itemTitle')]")
data = []

for pTitle in prodTitle:
    itemName = pTitle
    data.append([pTitle.text, pTitle.data_0, pTitle.data_1, ...])

columns = ['Title', 'Col_0', 'Col_1', ...]
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=columns)
```

Comment: it works perfectly, but how to add another column then write the file without index or titles?

Comment: I edited the answer to include the steps to add more columns and data to the DataFrame

Comment: And if i want to remove the index numbering?

Comment: you will have to create a row each iteration with the same columns as the main dataframe and appending them